# session.endConversation() doesn't help to generate new conversationId

Tags: botframework

I would like to generate new conversationId after 2 hours of no activity from user. So I wrote a timeout functions starts after 15000ms and calls session.endConversation();

After that when I send some message to bot it's considered as new conversation so I would expect it to generate new conversationId in next turn.

```
const handler = setTimeout(() => {
            session.endConversation();
        }, 15000);
```

Reproduction Steps:-

Send some message to bot, and grab/make a Note current conversationId from session.
then call session.endConversation() wherever you feel.
Again send some new message to bot, grab conversationId from session.
Both conversationId's should be different.

Comment: Maybe you can check this [Send proactive messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-proactive-messages?view=azure-bot-service-3.0)

Comment: Thanks. It does talk about sending proactive messages using proactive dialog.and doesn't talk about session.endConversation() & conversationId

Comment: Calling [`endConversation()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-end-conversation?view=azure-bot-service-3.0#send-an-endofconversation-activity) or sending an [endofconversation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-activities?view=azure-bot-service-3.0#endofconversation) activity is only meant to indicate to your bot that a conversation is over. (like sending it on closing the chat window etc)

Comment: Unfortunately there is not a simple way to refresh the conversationID within the scope of a frontend window beyond refreshing the window and reconnecting. That issue is currently being looked at [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/1122).

Comment: What you can do is hit directly against the `DirectLine API`'s conversation endpoint. It should return a conversation object with a brand new `conversationId`. Although the websocket's `streamUrl` will change so you might want to re-initialize the `BotChat.App` to make it work